# IOS MDM denying checkin request not working

Tags: ios, mdm

I have a custom mdm solution running for IOS.

during enrollment, I am using HTTP basic authentication to pass the user name and password to be verified against our db/AD.

if the user is denied access, I send a 401.

however, on the IOS side, it pops up an error that says "safari could not install a profile due to an unknown error". Seems like a pretty bad error where I want it to say access denied.

Also there's an issue that safari decides to cache the credential used, so I don't get a chance to re-enter the user/pass again unless I clear all the cookie/cache data.

Anyone have met this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to be issue with my code.

I've sent a 401, but actually the specification calls for a WWW-Authenticate header to be sent as well. With that added it, it's working normally now.

Answer (score -5):

Have you considered using a more widely tested MDM solution such as AirWatch?  A solution such as this has integration with AD and would be an excellent option for you to evaluate.